# Any way to open an application locally through aspx?

Tags: javascript, sql, internet-explorer, vbscript

So my goal is to have a web portal where our helpdesk users can lookup a user, find their computer(s) and click on the computer name to launch a remote-viewer application locally. I've attempted through, vb .net, javascript/asp, sql, and I'm out of ideas..

Here's some of the code already attempted.

```
  <script type = "text/javascript" >
    function go() {
            w = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell");
            w.run("cmd.exe /c C:\\SCCMRemoteView\\Remote\\CmRcViewer.exe ");
            return true;
    }
 </script>
```

Returns `"Unspecified Error"`
Also, tried the

```
 Shell, (var remote.exe, "CmRcViewer.exe","C:\SCCMRemote\Remote\","open","1")
```

Failed...

```
    Dim Rview As New Process
    Rview.StartInfo.FileName = ("C:\SCCMRemote\Remote\CmRcViewer.exe ")
```

Works, but not after its published to the website (I believe because the base code is aspx - not local)

I know the "Security" risks, but only members of our AD group will have access to the page - so it should be fine... Any ideas would be great!

Comment: Try adding the website to the Intranet (or local computer) zone on the client. And you need to do this with client-side scripts. ASPX code runs on the server, so it can't execute stuff on the client.

Answer (score 0):

This is not realistically feasible. The only browser that can support ActiveX calls is IE. IE has discontinued support for ActiveX with Windows 8, no matter which browser you use. With Windows 7, you have to run the browser in an elevated privileges mode (opening you up for those security issues you mentioned).

You can try this, but you will have to [register the protocol handler to an executable by making Registry entries on each machine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/aa767914%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). This process is not something that can be automated from the browser. Your users will have to download and execute something to create the handler.

It appears that some browsers will allow you to do the same thing with a browser based protocol handler, but it is not implemented everywhere.

Comment: That's not true. The Desktop Version of IE supports activex just like always. Only the Metro/ModenUI/Touch/silly/fullscreen Version of IE does not support activex/plugins.

Answer (score 0):

```
      Dim Address As String = Server.MapPath("~") & "\test.exe"
  Process.Start("explorer.exe", Address)
```

Answer (score 0):

try to use exec instead of run like so:

```
<script>

function Run() {
  try {
    var objShell = new ActiveXObject("wscript.shell");
    objShell.exec("C:\\SCCMRemoteView\\Remote\\CmRcViewer.exe ");

  } catch(e) {
    alert(e);
  }
}
</script>


<input type="button" name="btn01" onclick="Run()" value="click me">
```

Furthermore you have to change the security settings for YOUR SPECIFIC site in IE Settings->Security. add your site to the trusted sites and set the activex things... you will have to do that for each Computer/IE in which you want to use that activex/remote thing...